# Strange way to call a method from an instance object...

Tags: c++, class, object, methods

digging some codes, I found a curiously manner to call a method from an instance object which I will show in the example code bellow:

```
class Example{
public:
  void Print(){ std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;}
};

int main(){
  Example ex;
  ex.Example::Print(); // Why use this notation instead of just ex.Print();
  return 0;
}
```

There is any behaviour difference between **ex.Example::Print()** and the standard way **ex.Print()**? Why the author' code used the former instead of the latter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that `ex.Example::Print()` specifies that you want the version of `Print()` defined in the class `Example`.  In this particular example, there's no difference.  However, consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class One {
    int i;

  public:
    One(int ii) : i(ii) {}
    virtual void print() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

class Two : public One {
    int j;

  public:
    Two(int ii, int jj) : One(ii), j(jj) {}
    void print() override {
        One::print();
        std::cout << j << std::endl;
    }
};

class Three : public Two {
    int k;

  public:
    Three(int ii, int jj, int kk) : Two(ii, jj), k(kk) {}
    void print() override {
        Two::print();
        std::cout << k << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Three four(1, 2, 3);

    four.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    four.One::print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    four.Two::print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    four.Three::print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3

1

1
2

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 ex.Example::Print(); // Why use this notation instead of just ex.Print();
```

Given the posted code, that is the same as:

```
ex.Print();
```

It will make a difference only if name hiding comes into play and you want to be explicit about calling a particular version of the function.

Ex:

```
struct Foo
{
   void Print() const { std::cout << "Came to Foo::Print()\n"; }
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   void Print() const { std::cout << "Came to Bar::Print()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   Bar b;
   b.Print(); // Calls Bar::Print()
   b.Foo::Print();  // Calls Foo::Print()
}
```

That's just the mechanics of how things work. As a design choice, it will be better to use `virtual` functions:

```
struct Foo
{
   virtual void Print() const { std::cout << "Came to Foo::Print()\n"; }
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   virtual void Print() const { std::cout << "Came to Bar::Print()\n"; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference between calling `ex.Example::Print()` and `ex.Print()` in this example.

The only use/benefit of this invocation I can think of is with inheritance; You can explicitly call over-ridden method in parent class using this syntax from an instance of derived class.